# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::VERSION error while using rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am new to ruby on rails. I want to re-create a production setup on my local system for development purposes.I  seem to have run into a problem during migration of database.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 OS.  I have installed mysql-server, ruby 2.3.2 , rails 5.0, libmysqld-dev and mysql2 gem successfully. I was able to create a database and import the SQL file for table creation. To do pending migration, I executed `rake db:migrate`. I am getting the following error.

```
rake aborted!NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::VERSION
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:151:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.1/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:2:in `require'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.1/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.1/lib/activerecord/session_store.rb:1:in `require'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.1/lib/activerecord/session_store.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/IRIS/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/IRIS/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/raj/IRIS/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- activerecord-session_store
/home/raj/IRIS/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/IRIS/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/raj/IRIS/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Regarding the error in active_record_store.rb line number 151, the code is as follows:

```
if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR == 4
    require 'action_dispatch/session/legacy_support'
    ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore.send(:include, ActionDispatch::Session::LegacySupport)
end
```

Comment: I think the Rails version is different between your production and dev environment.

Comment: I checked it. It is the same.

Comment: However the error shown in line 151 of active_record_store.rb is regarding version. Not able to understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

During RVM installation rails latest version was also installed somehow. Removing all the gems and doing `bundle install` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below mentioned command

```
gem install activerecord
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I installed. I am still getting NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base error

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to the top of `active_record_store.rb` to see if it works?

```
require 'active_record/version'
```

Comment: I added. I got this new error.  rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base
Did you mean?  Base64